# Creating cache files with loop

Tags: php

I have a script to gather weather data for several cities from Json files (each city has a unique url for the Json)
Everything is working perfectly as it can be seen here:
[1](https://www.meteocaldas.com/previsao2.php): http://meteocaldas.com/previsao2.php 
However this example is just for 3 cities and I want to extend it to 40 cities so I need to create 40 cache files in order not to exceed maximum allowed requests. 
I am a begginer and the only way i could get this to work was by creating cache files one by one as you can see in the script. I tried several solutions to make a loop to create the cache files using things like for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) etc, but results were always error messages :-)
Is there an easy way to make a loop in this script to create cache files from city[0] to city[n]?
Thanks in advance for any help!

```
### Create drop down menu and array with cities
    <?php
    $arr = ["city0", "city1", "city2" ];
    $city = $arr[0];
    if( $_POST['city']){
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    }
    ?>

    <form name="f" id="a" method="post" action="">
    <select id="city" name="city" onchange="this.form.submit()" >                      

    <?php
foreach ($arr as $a){
if($a == $city){
       echo "<option value='{$a}' selected >$a</option>";
    }else{
       echo "<option value='{$a}' >$a</option>";
    }} ?>

   </select>
   </form>


### URL's for 5 day forecast's JSON for each city
    if ($city == $arr[0]) {$fIOURL = "http://www.city0.com" ;}
elseif ($city == $arr[1]) {$fIOURL = "http://www.city1.com" ;}
elseif ($city == $arr[2]) {$fIOURL = "http://www.city2.com" ;}

### CACHE City0 ###
if ($city == $arr[0]) {
if(file_exists('cache/'.$arr[0].'.txt')){ 
if (time()-filemtime('cache/'.$arr[0].'.txt') > 60 * 60) { 
unlink('cache/'.$arr[0].'.txt');
}
}
if(file_exists('cache/'.$arr[0].'.txt')){
    $rawData = file_get_contents('cache/'.$arr[0].'.txt');
    $forecastLoadedTime = filemtime('cache/'.$arr[0].'.txt');
}
else{
    $rawData = file_get_contents($fIOURL);
if($rawData!=""){
    file_put_contents('cache/'.$arr[0].'.txt',$rawData);
}
    $forecastLoadedTime = time();
}
$rawData = file_get_contents('cache/'.$arr[0].'.txt');
    $decoded = json_decode($rawData, true); 
}


### CACHE City1 (repeat process above but for $arr[1]###
if ($city == $arr[1]) {
if(file_exists('cache/'.$arr[1].'.txt')){ 
if (time()-filemtime('cache/'.$arr[1].'.txt') > 60 * 60) { 
unlink('cache/'.$arr[1].'.txt');
}
}
if(file_exists('cache/'.$arr[1].'.txt')){
    $rawData = file_get_contents('cache/'.$arr[1].'.txt');
    $forecastLoadedTime = filemtime('cache/'.$arr[1].'.txt');
}
else{
    $rawData = file_get_contents($fIOURL);
if($rawData!=""){
    file_put_contents('cache/'.$arr[1].'.txt',$rawData);
}
    $forecastLoadedTime = time();
}
$rawData = file_get_contents('cache/'.$arr[1].'.txt');
    $decoded = json_decode($rawData, true); 
}

### CACHE City2 ###
    (repeat process but now with $arr[2])
```

Comment: Maybe you should do another step and learn some object oriented programming to organize better your code. After that you can learn some framework, I strongly recommend [Laravel](https://laravel.com). With it, you will be able to do caching very easily, and many other things. Not your answer, just a suggestion.

Comment: if it was me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the name of the city as the value in your `select`, use the array index instead. This will simplify your code by allowing `$city` to be an index into the array of cities. Then you can take a similar approach to your caching code, using the city name (`= $arr[$city]`) to generate the cache file name and the URL for fetching:

```
$arr = ["city0", "city1", "city2" ];
$city = isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : 0;
?>
    <form name="f" id="a" method="post" action="">
    <select id="city" name="city" onchange="this.form.submit()" >                      
<?php
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    echo "<option value='$k'" . ($k == $city ? " selected" : "") . ">$v</option>\n";
}
?>
   </select>
   </form>
<?php
// create URL
$city_name = $arr[$city];
$fIOURL = "http://www.{$city_name}.com";
// check cache
$city_cache = "cache/{$city_name}.txt";
$cache_exists = file_exists($city_cache);
if (!$cache_exists || time() - filemtime($city_cache) > 60 * 60) { 
    // cache doesn't exist, or is no longer valid
    $rawData = file_get_contents($fIOURL);
    if ($rawData != "") {
        // if we successfully fetched data, recreate the cache
        $cache_exists = file_put_contents($city_cache, $rawData);
    }
}
if ($cache_exists) {
    // fetch the data (either cached or freshly loaded) from the cache file
    $rawData = file_get_contents($city_cache);
    $forecastLoadedTime = filemtime($city_cache);
}
else {
    // some sort of error message here
    $rawData = "No data available for $city_name!";
}
$decoded = json_decode($rawData, true);
```

**Update**

Since your API URLs are all based on a number that is dependent on the city, the simplest way to generate them is to change your array of city names to be indexed by that number. So you would change the first two lines of code above to something like:

```
$arr = array(31927 => "city0", 16765 => "city1", 29832 => "city2");
$city = isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : array_keys($arr)[0];
```

Note that we now get the default city as the first key in the array (with this example data it would be 31927). Then you would change the URL generation code to:

```
$fIOURL = "http://wwwsite/index.php?api_lang=pt&localidad={$city}&affiliate_id=xxxx&v=3.0";
```

Comment: My guess is the URLs aren't as simple as shown here. You could use `$arr = ['city0' => 'http://whatever', ...]`, with commensurate changes to your use of the `$city` variable (which is now both the array index and the city name). Also, I don't think you need the `unlink` call, as `file_put_contents` will overwrite it by default. The rest is more or less what I was about to write up. :-)

Comment: @GregSchmidt good point about the URL, I've added a note about how to get them from an array. I think a separate array is probably simplest. And thanks for the heads-up on `file_put_contents`, it's not a function I use often so had forgotten it overwrites by default.

Comment: Thank you so much Nick and GregSchmidt. In fact the url's aren't that simple but the onlly thing that changes between them is not the city name but the city number. Each town has a number  assigned to it in the url. I should have been more explicit on that but I am going to try Nick's code and GregSchmidt's tips and I will let you know the results. Thanks once again.

Comment: @MeteoCaldas if you can give more information on the actual URLs I'm sure I can modify the answer to suit.

Comment: Thank you so much Nick for your help cause my trouble now is exactly with the url's! Url format is this: wwwsite/index.php?api_lang=pt&localidad=31927&affiliate_id=xxxx&v=3.0  The 5 digit number identifies the city and that is the only thing that changes between url's. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MeteoCaldas see my update for how to deal with the URLs. Note that I also changed the original code slightly for the cache miss case to ensure that `$cache_exists` gets set properly the first time that a city is accessed.

Comment: @Nick Thank you soooo much! Everything is working like a charm and it can be seen here <http://www.meteocaldas.com/previsao3.php>. It would take me many many hours of trial-error to achieve this result! Marvellous!